# Taking cluster of points located near each other and creating just 1 point located in center using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, clustering

I am using ArcMap.

I am doing a quick project and want to take these points and create just 1 point for each cluster located in about the center of the cluster.

Is there a tool to help me do this?

I should have 5 points based on the clusters.

[image]

Comment: Buffer, dissolve, centroid of resulting polygons

Comment: Consider the [Mean Center](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/mean-center.htm) tool?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using Aggregate Points tool from cartography toolbox. However it might result in:

[image]

If you get wrong aggregation distance. You'll get it right after few iterations.

You might also try script below, after attaching it to tool:
[image]

Just name your points "NODES" in a table of mxd content, run tool to get something like this:

[image]

Script:

```
# GROUPS POINTS INTO GIVEN NUMBER OF CLUSTERS
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
nearTable=r'in_memory\near'
lines = r'in_memory\lines'
manyPgons=r'in_memory\many'
dissolvedPgons=r'in_memory\dissolved'

required=int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
closest=3
theNodesLayer = "NODES"
d=arcpy.Describe(theNodesLayer)
SR=d.spatialReference
nOld =0
while True:
    arcpy.analysis.GenerateNearTable(theNodesLayer,theNodesLayer, nearTable, closest="ALL", closest_count=str(closest),location="LOCATION")
    arcpy.management.XYToLine(nearTable, lines, "FROM_X", "FROM_Y", "NEAR_X", "NEAR_Y", "GEODESIC", "", SR)
    arcpy.management.FeatureToPolygon(lines,manyPgons)
    arcpy.management.Dissolve(manyPgons, dissolvedPgons, multi_part="SINGLE_PART")
    result=arcpy.management.GetCount(dissolvedPgons)
    nFsel=int(result.getOutput(0))
    arcpy.AddMessage("%i group(s) with %i neighbours" %(nFsel,closest))
    if nFsel<=required:break
    if nOld==nFsel:break
    closest+=1; nOld=nFsel
outPolygons=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(dissolvedPgons, outPolygons)
```

NOTES:

- script requires advanced license
- it will fail with number of points in the cluster less than 3, but it honours selection of points in your layer.

Simply use feature to point afterwards, or add coordinates to your points and find their mean values per nearest polygon.